# Fatal Error Mage.php on line 329 - Magento on Windows 10

Tags: php, error, magento-1, windows

I have this code in Magento (installed on Windows 10):

```
<?php
include_once('C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php');
$rootMagento = Mage::getBaseDir();
$files = scandir($rootMagento);
$count = sizeof($files);
for ($i =0; $i< $count; $i++) {
    if ($files[$i]=='productData.txt'){
        $fileAperto = fopen($files[$i], "r");
        while (!feof($fileAperto)){
            $nome = trim(substr($buffer,0,20));
            if ($nome =='') {
                Mage::log ('manca il nome');
            }

        }
    }
}
?>
```

and, when I run it, I have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 329

I try also to print some variable's value but system.log file is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Magento in a custom PHP script, you always have to initialize it first:

```
Mage::app();
```

Afterwards, `Mage::getBaseDir()` will not throw this error anymore

Comment: @Federica. Welcome to SE. If an answer helped you solve your problem, mark it as accepted.